# Custom Appender in Karaf Decanter Not working

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to create a custom appender using Decanter as mentioned [here](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/decanter/latest-1/index.html#_custom_appender). My goal is to listen to all logs output by karaf bundles and display it in console. I am using Karaf 3.0.4 under Apache Servicemix 6.1.0

I have added Decanter feature repository in Karaf & then installed collector-log and appender-log as mentioned in the Decanter documentation.

My custom appender looks like below:-

```
package com.jabong.karaf.decanter.appender.elklog;

import org.osgi.service.event.Event;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;

public class ELKLogAppender implements EventHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    for (String name : event.getPropertyNames()) {
        System.out.println("Custom Debraj" + name + ":" + event.getProperty(name));
    }
    }
}
```

My `Activator` looks like below:-

```
package com.jabong.karaf.decanter.appender.elklog;

import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventConstants;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    private ServiceRegistration registration;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) {
    ELKLogAppender appender = new ELKLogAppender();
    Dictionary<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<>();
    properties.put(EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, "decanter/collect/*");
    registration = bundleContext.registerService(EventHandler.class, appender, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) {
    if (registration != null) {
        registration.unregister();
    }
    }
}
```

My pom.xml looks like below:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jabong.karaf.decanter.appender</groupId>
    <artifactId>elklog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>Apache Karaf :: Decanter :: Appender :: ELKLog</name>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- OSGi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.jabong.karaf.decanter.appender.elklog.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I was able to install the bundle correctly in Karaf by placing it in `deploy` folder.

```
332 | Active    |  80 | 0.0.1                              | basecomponent                                               
333 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.1                              | Apache Karaf :: Decanter :: API                             
334 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.1                              | Apache Karaf :: Decanter :: Collector :: Log                
337 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.1                              | Apache Karaf :: Decanter :: Appender :: Log                 
339 | Active    |  80 | 0.0.1                              | Apache Karaf :: Decanter :: Appender :: ELKLog 
340 | Active    |  80 | 2.4.0                              | Commons IO                                                  
341 | Active    |  80 | 1.0.1                              | Apache Karaf :: Decanter :: Collector :: File
```

My `org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` in Karaf looks like below:-

```
# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, osgi:VmLogAppender
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer

# To avoid flooding the log when using DEBUG level on an ssh connection and doing log:tail
log4j.logger.org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession = INFO

# CONSOLE appender not used by default
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %X | %m%n

# File appender
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %X | %m%n
log4j.appender.out.file=${karaf.data}/log/servicemix.log
log4j.appender.out.append=true
log4j.appender.out.maxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.out.maxBackupIndex=10

# Sift appender
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=bundle.name
log4j.appender.sift.default=servicemix
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=${karaf.data}/log/$\\{bundle.name\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true
```

But I am not seeing any message on the console. Even though I am seeing many logs in `data/servicemix.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg, changing to

`log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, osgi:*`

from

`log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, osgi:VmLogAppender`

solved the issue.